# What is the fastest way to sort objects based on keys using C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting

I have an array `T *O` of objects and an array of keys `double *K` defined by `K[i] = f(O[i]))`. Let us say `sizeof(T)` is not too large, maybe `32` bytes at most.

I want to sort `O` with respect to ordering `O[i] < O[j]` iff `K[i] < K[j]`. This is performance critical, so I would prefer to use an optimised library. Libraries ips4o and Google's highway quicksort have the same interface as `std::sort` which lets us sort `K` fast. An option would be to define `P[i] = (i, K[i])`, sort that based on the second tuple argument, and then write `O2[i] = O[P[i]]; memcpy(O, O2, ...);`. However, this is not in-place and the final step has atrocious cache behaviour. Is there a faster method? Maybe a library that mirrors the data movement of `K` in `O`?

If this question is too general, let us take `sizeof(T) = 16`, and a `x86-64` CPU with `avx512` extensions.

Comment: How fast is your `f` function? Is it OK to call it 2*n*log2(n) times (such as in std::sort and std::stable_sort)? The minimum number of calls in n; in this case the results must be cached in a helper array.

Comment: What fast sorting libraries have you tried? How much faster are they than std::sort? What are your benchmark results? Run the benchmarks with a simple (but incorrect) comparator function. How much faster do they become?

Comment: In your benchmarks, indicate how many times the `f` function was called, and how much time was spent inside it.

Comment: Are any of your keys `nan`?  If so, that can really mess up sorting.  It can be "fixed" by taking [`std::fpclassify`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify) into account.  Another option is to use a `std::vector<std::size_t> i(n);` numbered from 0 to n-1 as indexes into the `O` and `K`, and sort those indexes with respect to your criteria.

Comment: @pts `f` is fast,  `5` cycles. There is no difference between this comparator function and `<` on doubles. I have used `ips4o` which obtains a speedup of about `30`. There is too much template magic going on to profile how much time is spend in `f`, but I think this shows it is not the bottleneck.

Comment: How well values of `f(O[i]))` are distributed? Do you have some memory limit? It may turn out that bucket sorting will be fastest solution

Comment: If you are sorting a sufficiently large number of elements, and you don't mind doing some coding, you could chop it into sections and sort them on different threads, before merging the results. @MarekR I don't think bucket sort is suitable for doubles. I think you need a comparison sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first trick is to find a sorting library that doesn't require full LegacyRandom Access iterators.  The problem is LegacyRandomAccess iterators *require* that `*it` be a real reference to real data.

The more modern `std::random_access_iterator` allows `*it` to return a proxy object.

Once you have this, you create iterators whose state is an index `i`, and whose `<` is based off `K[i]`, but when swapped/assigned they also swap/assign `O[i]`.

`std::sort` requires LegacyRandomAccessIterators.  I strongly suspect most other modern algorithms, even ones that copy its signature, do not; that is why `std::random_access_iterator` was written.

```
template<class K, class V, class Cmp=std::less<void> >
struct key_sorted_refs {
  K& k;
  V& v;
  friend bool operator<(key_sorted_refs lhs, key_sorted_refs rhs) {
    return Cmp{}(lhs.k, rhs.k);
  }
};
```

then your iterators are boilerplate wrapped around an iterator, whose `*` returns a `key_sorted_refs{ K[i], V[i] )`.

So long as the algorithm doesn't use temporary swap objects it should work.

Comment: [`std::ranges::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) then?

Comment: @Caleth I believe so; I am not an expert on std::ranges.